# Call javascript function with jquery value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following form:

```html
<form action="myaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span class="required">*</span>Email</td>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="moosendid" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="submit" class="button" />
    </form>
```

and a javascript function:

```
function MoosendMail(moomail) {...}
```

I need on submit to run the function before the action of the form. I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#submit1').on('click',function() {
    MoosendMail($('input#moosendid').val());
  });
});
```

with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not add the callback on submit of the form? You've got it on the click of the button which probably fires _after_ the submit.

Comment: *with no success.* - meaning what? What happens? Nothing? Something? Errors?

Comment: The function i use is from moosend and i am trying to get user email to put it in a mailing list. I have tested function alone and its working, but this form is registration form with a checkbox for newsletter registration, so i wanted if clicked yes to register user and execute function to put user in mailing list

Comment: You added method type post on your form. So you need to first stop submitting form by e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the submit handler and then prevent the default action of the submit button I believe.

```
function MoosendMail(moomail){
    alert(moomail);
};

  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();     
        MoosendMail($('input#moosendid').val());
        this.submit(); // only after you are done (be careful of async requests) and want to submit.
    });
  });
```

I hope this help.

Comment: It seems that when i console.log the email value from input before submit, i get nothing, like i don;t get the value. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure.  The alert shows my file.  Can you update your question with code you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

You added `method` type `post` on your form. So you need to first stop submitting form by `e.preventDefault()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#submit1').on('click',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 
    MoosendMail($('input#moosendid').val());
  });
});

function MoosendMail(moomail) {
   console.log(moomail);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="myaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <span class="required">*</span>Email</td>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="moosendid" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: In this example after MoosendMail function i wrote this:console.log(" MoosendMail("+$('input#moosendid').val()+")"); and on submit i got in console MoosendMail(). It seems like i don't get the value

Comment: You added as string so you are getting string. If you run my code here and submit form you see it's working. or you need to type `console.log(MoosendMail($('input#moosendid').val()));`